# PN5180 SEND PPSE COMMAND (For EMV Cards)

Tags: nfc, credit-card, apdu, emv

I have a pn5180 reader. I can send WUPA command to an EMV card (ISO 14443-A) with PN5180. I can also get the UID information of the card. I can also send a RATS command to the card and get the ATS statement, which is the answer.

However, after sending a RATS command (a PICC receiving a RATS command goes into a "protocol state") some strange situations can occur. These can be listed as:
a- I cannot read a Register of pn5180.
b- When I send a PPSE command, the responses I get are 0xFF.
c- I get a response to the DESELECT command, but when I send WUPA to the card again, a problem occurs.

In short, why doesn't a PPSE command I send after the RATS command return a proper response? I wonder if some adjustments need to be made before or after the RATS command?

Note:I've asked the same question in the NXP community and haven't gotten an answer yet.

Comment: comment the logs also, maybe someone could help..

Comment: @Deniz As you've been asked in the previous commend, it would be better if you supplied additional information. It can be a lot of things and it's hard to tell based on these details. You may want to tell the community a bit more about the card as well as in certain situations this might be the cause (like payment cards in production environment may go mute if you do not follow specs, and therefore should not be used for development purposes).